# How can I fix this mypy "Incompatible return value type" for my Enum like class in my Python project?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy

In our project we never use Enum we use SimpleEnum which is defined like this:

```
class SimpleEnum:
    @classmethod
    def values(cls):
        return {
            getattr(cls, name)
            for name in dir(cls)
            if not name.startswith("_") and not callable(getattr(cls, name))
        }
```

Now for something like this:

```
class MySimpleEnum(SimpleEnum):
    completed = "completed"
    parse = "parse"


def foo() -> MySimpleEnum:
    return MySimpleEnum.parse
```

I get mypy error:

```
error: Incompatible return value type (got "str", expected "MySimpleEnum")  [return-value]
```

This is a super simplified use case in a hundred thousand of lines project. I can't just switch to Enum. How can I change SimpleEnum to allow code hinting like I'm trying to do (if even possible)? The change must not change the behavior of SimpleEnum (since it's used hundred of times in the project).

Comment: The best you'll probably be able to do is something like `Literal["complete", "parse"]`. Fundamentally `MySimpleEnum.parse` isn't `MySimpleEnum` or an instance of `MySimpleEnum`, it's just a string.

Comment: Basically, your `SimpleEnum` **isn't an enum**, so you can't use it as one, from a typing perspective. You just have class variables that refer to`str` objects. Also, I think you meant ` -> MySimpleEnum` instead of `type[MySimpleEnum]` (the latter definitely doesn't make sense)

Comment: I would suggest a code refactor/modernization. `enum` is the best choice by all means: it has been available since Python 3.4, and supports proper type hinting. Do this for once and your (future) colleagues won't have to worry about this very same problem.

Comment: Yeah, may be able to use `StrEnum` to help with the refactoring (it may even "just work" with only inheriting). But even then, I would suggest actually using a regular `enum.Enum`

Answer (score 2):

Here is one potential clunky workaround:

```
import typing

class SimpleEnum:
    @classmethod
    def values(cls):
        return {
            getattr(cls, name)
            for name in dir(cls)
            if not name.startswith("_") and not callable(getattr(cls, name))
        }

MySimpleEnumValue = typing.NewType(str)

class MySimpleEnum(SimpleEnum):
    completed = MySimpleEnumValue("completed")
    parse = MySimpleEnumValue("parse")


def foo() -> MySimpleEnumValue:
    return MySimpleEnum.parse
```

This relies on `typing.NewType`. The new type isn't actually a new type, it is *only* for static analysis purposes, and `MySimpleEnumValue(x)` simply returns `x`, so the values are actually just instances of `str`, but the static type checker should consider them distinct.

And of course, it requires you to mint a new `typing.NewType` for every `SimpleEnum` subclass. But this maybe will require the least amount of refactoring.

But really, you should refactor to use an `enum.Enum`. You could potentially just use `enum.StrEnum` to make the transition easier, although,

```
import enum

class SimpleEnum(enum.StrEnum):
    @classmethod
    def values(cls):
        return set(cls.__members__.values())
```

Note, in this case, the members *are a subtype of string*:

```
In [19]: import enum
    ...:
    ...: class SimpleEnum(enum.StrEnum):
    ...:     @classmethod
    ...:     def values(cls):
    ...:         return set(cls.__members__.values())
    ...:

In [20]: class MySimpleEnum(SimpleEnum):
    ...:     completed = "completed"
    ...:     parse = "parse"
    ...:

In [21]: MySimpleEnum.values()
Out[21]: {<MySimpleEnum.completed: 'completed'>, <MySimpleEnum.parse: 'parse'>}
```

But they are strings:

```
In [22]: print(MySimpleEnum.completed)
completed

In [23]: MySimpleEnum.completed + " the job"
Out[23]: 'completed the job'
```

However, it will break if anywhere in your code, you test for the `str` type *specifically* (there are places that happens in the standard library, see the [notes in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#enum.StrEnum)). e.g. something does:

```
if type(x) is str:
    ...
```

Instead of

```
if isinstance(x, str):
   ...
```

The other place is if you use the `repr` of the string anywhere, which will use the enum `__repr__` not `str.__repr__`

Comment: This GitHub issue might be of interest: [Enum with `str` or `int` Mixin Breaking Change in Python 3.11](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/100458).

Answer (score 1):

You can lie to the type checker and inherit from `Enum`, even though you don't use it at runtime.

```py
import typing as t

if t.TYPE_CHECKING:
    from enum import Enum
else:
    Enum = object

class SimpleEnum(Enum): ...
    
class MySimpleEnum(SimpleEnum):
    completed = "completed"
    parse = "parse"

def foo() -> MySimpleEnum:
    return MySimpleEnum.parse  # OK
```

I assume that your `SimpleEnum` implementation actually has some `__init_subclass__` or `metaclass=...` magic to make the runtime actually behave like enums, otherwise I don't advise doing this.